# iwlwifi crashes after a kernel update to the 5.3.0-43 kernel

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

After using the following commands to install docker:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo sh get-docker.sh
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

and rebooting, my `wlan0` device is no longer available (and was replaced by `docker0`). I disabled the docker service `systemctl disable docker`) and rebooted again. I now have the following debugging info:

[image]

```
sterlingbutters@butters-ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux butters-ubuntu 5.3.0-43-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 16 13:29:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
sterlingbutters@butters-ubuntu:~$ sudo lspci -vs 04:00.0
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 69, NUMA node 0
    Memory at 92d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number a0-af-bd-ff-ff-c3-3f-52
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

```
sterlingbutters@butters-ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   35.811059] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   36.762569] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1654887522.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   38.612055] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3168, REV=0x220
[   38.629869] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Can't parse phy_sku in B0, empty sections
[   38.629872] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to read NVM: -61
[   38.629873] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[   38.631034] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   38.631035] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Status: 0x00000080, count: 6
[   38.631036] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.1654887522.0
[   38.631037] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[   38.631038] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[   38.631039] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   38.631039] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0004171E | branchlink2
[   38.631040] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000446B2 | interruptlink1
[   38.631041] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000446B2 | interruptlink2
[   38.631041] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[   38.631042] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
[   38.631042] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x07030000 | data3
[   38.631043] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   38.631044] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000011FD | tsf low
[   38.631044] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   38.631045] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   38.631046] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000011FD | time gp2
[   38.631046] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000009 | uCode revision type
[   38.631047] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000001D | uCode version major
[   38.631047] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x62A39462 | uCode version minor
[   38.631048] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000220 | hw version
[   38.631049] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00C89200 | board version
[   38.631049] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00110188 | hcmd
[   38.631050] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00022000 | isr0
[   38.631051] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   38.631051] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000002 | isr2
[   38.631052] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004000C0 | isr3
[   38.631052] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   38.631053] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00110188 | last cmd Id
[   38.631054] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[   38.631054] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000094 | l2p_control
[   38.631055] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   38.631056] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   38.631056] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   38.631057] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000007 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   38.631057] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x16070617 | timestamp
[   38.631058] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00341018 | flow_handler
[   38.631065] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   38.631070] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   38.631075] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   38.631080] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   38.631085] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   38.631089] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   38.631094] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   38.631099] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   38.631104] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   38.631108] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   38.631113] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   38.631118] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   38.631123] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   38.631127] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[   38.642872] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -61
```

```
sterlingbutters@butters-ubuntu:~$ ifconfig -a
enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 70:85:c2:52:23:dd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0x92f00000-92f20000  

enp5s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 70:85:c2:52:23:df  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x92c00000-92c1ffff  

enx00e04c680d9c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:e0:4c:68:0d:9c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5519  bytes 399125 (399.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5519  bytes 399125 (399.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
sterlingbutters@butters-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

```
sterlingbutters@butters-ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:69 memory:92d00000-92d01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: 70:85:c2:52:23:df
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=0. 4-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 memory:92c00000-92c1ffff ioport:3000(size=32) memory:92c20000-92c23fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: 70:85:c2:52:23:dd
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:47 memory:92f00000-92f1ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:5.2
       logical name: enx00e04c680d9c
       serial: 00:e0:4c:68:0d:9c
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.11 duplex=half link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

```
sterlingbutters@butters-ubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep iwl 
iwlmvm                401408  0
mac80211              851968  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               348160  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              712704  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

Any ideas why my wireless interface would've disappeared because of docker? Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not because of dpcker. It's because you updated kernel. Boot with a previous kernel and it should be OK.

Comment: @Pilot6 Trying that now

Comment: And how it happend that you have 5.3.0-43 kernel? Is `proposed` repo enabled? The current kernel is 5.3.0-42. The next one is under testing.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes that worked - and it looks that way: 
`deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-proposed restricted universe multiverse main`

Comment: That was a bad idea to enable `propsoed`. It is disabled by default. remove that kernel and disable `proposed`.

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't remember enabling it but I will disable and remember that

Comment: It appears to be a very recent bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206329 I will try to work out a solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the 5.3.0-43 kernel. This kernel has not been released to Ubuntu and can be found in `proposed` repo.

Remove this kernel and disable `proposed` repo.